# "Higher-order" generics in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am not sure about the label, but I have this in mind (it has semantics of [bimap](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-3.2.0.1/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html) from Haskell):

```
bimap<A, B, C, D, Bif extends Bifunctor>(mapFnA: (a: A) => B, mapFnB: (c: C) => D, input: Bif<A, C>): Bif<B, D>;
```

TSC complained about `Bif` not having parameters, so I added them:

```
bimap<A, B, C, D, Bif<any, any> extends Bifunctor<any, any>>(mapFnA: (a: A) => B, mapFnB: (c: C) => D, input: Bif<A, C>): Bif<B, D>;
```

But now it is completely broken (like over seven hundred lines of errors).

Question: **Is the idea I want to achieve possible (if so how?), or is the type system of TypeScript too limited to express this?**

Comment: @kennytm Yes, it seems like so. Didn't really know what to search for, so didn't found that. Voting for closing.

Comment: Yes. These are usually called "Higher-[kinded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) types".